# Kurze Glückwunschformeln zum Neujahr

Tags: formality, politeness

Gibt es kurze Glückwunschformeln zum Neujahr für offizielle Anlässe? (z.B. Behörde, Geschäftspartner usw.)

„Einen guten Rutsch“ klingt mir etwas umgangssprachlich. Etwa „ein frohes neues Jahr“ ist schon etwas zu lang.

Was kann man für solche Fälle verwenden?

Comment: Sucht du etwas für mündlich oder schriftlich? Wenn man sich das erste Mal im neuen Jahr sieht, sagt man bei uns kurz "Frohes neues Jahr!"

Comment: Wieso zu lang? Für Deine kostbare Zeit? Um es auf dem Weg zur Kantine jemandem zuzurufen, ohne den Schritt zu verlangsamen? Das eine sind 5 Silben, das andere 6. "Frohes Neues" sind 4 aber auch schon sehr informell. "Prost Neujahr" 3, auch informell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es gibt hier zwei Möglichkeiten:

1. Du schreibst Glückwünsche zum Jahresende und möchtest deinem Gegenüber *im Voraus* ein gutes Neues wünschen;
2. Du nimmst nach den Feiertagen wieder Kontakt auf und wünschst dem Gegenüber *noch nachträglich* ein gutes Neues.

Die zweite Möglichkeit beantwortet eine Karte des *[Atlasses der deutschen Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r8-f1a-b-2/):*

[image: Karte der Neujahrswünsche am ersten Januar]

Wie man sehen kann, hängt es con der Gegend ab. In Süddeutschland und weiten Teilen Österreichs und der Schweiz wäre »Gutes Neues« oder »Gutes neues Jahr« die Formel der Wahl, in den südlichen neuen Bundesländern »Gesundes neues Jahr« und im Norden und Westen »Frohes neues Jahr«. Alle diese Formeln sind meines Erachtens durchaus für offizielle Anlässe tauglich.

Auf für die erste Möglichkeit gibt es eine Karte des *[Atlasses](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r8-f1c-2/)* – jedoch sieht die etwas eindeutiger und für dich wahrscheinlich unbefriedigender aus:

[image: Wünsche zu Silvester]

Wie man sieht, wird im Alltag und in der gesprochenen Sprache (denn genau das frägt der Atlas) ausschließlich ein *guter Rutsch* gewünscht. Dazu schreiben die Auswerter:

> Dass man sich zu Silvester *einen guten Rutsch* ins neue Jahr wünscht (und erst ab Beginn des neuen Jahres *ein gutes/frohes/gesundes neues Jahr),* hat sich offenbar im ganzen Sprachraum durchgesetzt. Dies ist jedenfalls im Süden anscheinend eine neuere Erscheinung, so heißt es am 31.12.1993 in der österreichischen Zeitung *Die Presse* [sic!] noch: „Du liebe Zeit, habe ich gegeifert, als vor Jahren der *Gute Rutsch* Mode wurde und das gute alte Glückwünschen zum Jahreswechsel abkam. Ist ja auch wirklich nicht gerade geistvoll; sehr salopp, flapsig, um nicht zu sagen schnoddrig.“

Der Kommentar wird dir wohl ein bisschen aus der Seele sprechen.

Was sind denn die Alternativen? Gehört und gelesen habe ich Konstruktionen wie:

> Und kommen Sie gut ins neue Jahr.
>
> Einen guten Übergang ins neue Jahr.
>
> Einen schönen Jahreswechsel.

Und ähnliches. Am ehesten würde ich noch die erste Variante hiervon bevorzugen. Allerdings ist es in den Tagen vor Neujahr inzwischen so üblich, sich von allem und jedem mit *guten Rutsch* zu verabschieden, dass ich diese Formel auch in offizielleren Briefen hernehmen würde.

Comment: ＋１ sofort weil Bilder vom *Atlas  zur  deutschen  Alltagssprache*.

Comment: Wow. Danke für so eine ausführliche Antwort!